# Reflection to get within convex polygon

Tags: contest-math, combinatorial-geometry, reflection

Let $P$ be a convex polygon, and let $A_1$ be a point on the same plane as $P$.

Prove that we can find an integer $n$, and points $A_2,A_3,\ldots,A_n$, such that $A_{i+1}$ is a reflection of $A_i$ with respect to some side of $P$, and $A_n$ lies within $P$.

[Source: Hungarian competition problem]

Answer (score 0):

Say that you have your convex polygon $P$ and sides $A_1,A_2,\cdots A_k$. Now, reflect $P$ across side $A_i$ to $P'$. Keep doing that; reflect $P'$ across some new side, etc ,etc. It is easy to see (but you have to do some induction -where you'll also use convexity- to make it rigorous) that in this way you can cover the whole plane. This can actually be used to answer your original question:

See, the point is that if $A$ and $B$ are sides of your original polygon $P$ and $P'=s_B\cdot P$ is the reflection across $B$, then $s_B\cdot A$ is one of the new sides of $P'$. But how can we express $s_{s_B\cdot_A}$, the reflection across this new side? Well $$s_{s_B\cdot_A}=s_B\cdot s_A\cdot s_B$$ This is not difficult to see: First $s_B\cdot s_A\cdot s_B$ is a reflection because it is the composition of an *odd* number of reflections. Now, all that's left is to check that the fixed points of the new reflection are exactly the line $s_B\cdot A$. Indeed $$s_B\cdot s_A\cdot s_B\big( s_B(a)\big) =s_B\cdot s_A(a)=s_B(a) $$ So $s_B(a)$ is fixed for all $a$ in the line of $A$, so $s_B\cdot A$ is the fixed line of the new reflection and we are done.

That means that reflecting across one of the new lines can be expressed as a composition of reflections across the original sides of the polygon. That is, if we are allowed to reflect across the original sides of $P$, we are really allowed to reflect across any of the new sides of the new $P'$ that the above process describes.

Then as we can fill all space with some $P'$, we pick one that contains our point and we use this (bigger but allowed) set of reflections to send this $P'$ to our original $P$ and hence our point inside $P$ as well.